# ASP.NET MVC - The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am following this guide to add security to a website I am developing:

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Security And Creating User Role](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97)

The problem is that when I started with it, I had two connection strings in the app the defaultconnection and the real one (created by me).

I've replaced the default one wherever it was being used and now when I try to start my application and run the code for creating the user roles:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandUsers();
    }

    // In this method we will create default User roles and Admin user for login   
    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            roleManager.Create(role);
        }
```

It always fails in the line:

```
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
```

with the error:

> The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

I saw in the defaultconnection database (which I already deleted) that there were several tables related to Users.

I expected the application to create them as well in the new database but it is not working.

I've already checked several of the question posted with the same error but none of them seem to solve my error...

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you tried update the database manually by using `Update-Database` in Package Manager?

Comment: Yes @CristianSzpisjak, with no error, but no result either

Comment: Did the DbContext use the correct connectionstring?

Comment: Yes, now it does

Comment: That was the fix?

Comment: No, no, I meant that at the moment of asking here, there was only one connection string and that one was the correct one.

Comment: Delete your db and start the app .. it will detect that no db exists and recreate one with all tables

Comment: I did as you suggested @ModarNa, but it has created the same database that there already was (no tables for user credentials...).

Comment: Humm .. maybe comment the createRolesandUsers function and try starting the app and register a new user

Comment: That did the trick, I have now the tables in the database. But I still get the same error as before, it seems it is closer to be solved tough... :)

Comment: Your `ApplicationDbContext` inherits `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` or `DbContext`?

Comment: Inherits from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>